# Blocking images from 3rd party sources from loading by reading LocalStorage

Tags: html, image

I am creating a website, and would like to give users a chance to block 3rd party elements ( mostly images ) from loading on the site to decrease the loading speed. I have already used lazy load on unnecessary images, but would like to give users the option to never load the images at all. What can I do here?
I have tried using CSS hide property, but the image is still loaded, but not visible. Is there any way to stop images from loading?

Comment: Add CSP (Content Security Policy) in your web server config and allow only the assets you know they should be loaded from.

Comment: @Snow - consider using a data attribute for the images. Set this attribute to the url to load, if indeed the image is to be loaded. Check the localStorage, then use js to copy the data attribute to the src attribute for the images that should be loaded.

Comment: @ManishJangir I am doing only front-end development

Comment: @enhzflep Could you help with an example or a website a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Only intended to demonstrate a way of specifying the image
but not actually loading it. You'll need to work out how you want to store a do/don't load flag for each image in `localStorage`.

Perhaps an array of true/false values.... (the .forEach method actually supplies an object, a loop/collection index and the collection it comes from/the array object whose .forEach method was called - in this example, instead of using

```
images.forEach( 
                img => {
```

I could have done

```
images.forEach( 
                (img,index,collection) => {
                // use index here as index into array retrieved
                // from localStorage.
```

**Example**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    // TODO: Add code to
    // get data from localStorage
    
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
    images.forEach( 
                    img => {
                        let shouldLoad = false;
                        
                        // TODO: Add code to 
                        // check current image against retrieved data
                        // to see if it should be loaded
                        
                        // example-code. 
                        // I'm just relying on the image's
                        // class attribute
                        if (img.classList.contains('dontLoad') == false)
                            shouldLoad = true;
                            
                        if (shouldLoad == true)
                            img.src = img.dataset.url;
                    }
                );
}
</script>
<style>
img{
    border: solid 1px red;
    min-width: 32px;
    min-height: 32px;
}

<!--
    dontLoad is just used to flag images for loading
-->
dontLoad{
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img data-url='../gfx07.jpg'/>
<img class='dontLoad' data-url='../heart.png'/>
<img data-url='../carColour.jpg'/>
<img class='dontLoad' data-url='../s13.bmp'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you...

I had to comment out the localStorage due to sandboxed but if you add this cscript in the head it should work

```js
var enabled = true;

function checkenabled() {
    if (enabled) {
        //add your code here to load images
    } 
}

function changeenabled() {
    if (enabled) {
        //localStorage.setItem('enabled', 'false');
        enabled = false;
        document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'disbaled';
        //localStorage.getItem('enabled');
        checkenabled();
    } else {
        //localStorage.setItem('enabled', 'true');
        enabled = true;
        document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'enabled';
        //localStorage.getItem('enabled');
        checkenabled();
    }
}
checkenabled();
```

```html
<button id='button' onclick='changeenabled();'>enabled</button>
```